# Table caption is indented

Tags: tables, indentation, els-cas

I am using `cas-dc.cls` for my article. If I start to my table with the `\begin{table*}`, table is generated fine but the caption is indented. If I remove the asterisk like `\begin{table}`, then indentation disappears but this time texts and the table are overlaps. Here is the beginning of my TeX file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\myhl}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\hl{#1}}}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}

\crefname{algocf}{alg.}{algs.}
\Crefname{algocf}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}

\aboverulesep=0ex 
\belowrulesep=0ex 

\newcolumntype{X}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

I don't want to copy all the parts of my table here in order to avoid the mess, but I hope the following part will be helpful to understand my problem:

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Statistical test results for DKP}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}
```

The above part gives the following result:

[image]

If I remove the `*`, I get this:

[image]

Could you guys please help me to solve the problem? I mean, I want no overlaps and no indentation.

Comment: you should provide an example document but if you use a column wide float  by removing `*` you need to width to be `\columnwidth` not `\textwidth`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did what you said, now it shrunk middle of the page.

Comment: if you provide an example someone will debug, But applying scaling to a table will never make nice results it will be better to choose a suitable font size, such as `\small`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by comment outing the following line in the `cas-common.sty`

```
\cs_new:Npn \__make_tbl_caption:nn #1#2
{
  %\l_tbl_align_tl <-- THIS LINE
  \skip_vertical:N \l_tbl_abovecap_skip 
  {\parbox{ \dimexpr(\l_tbl_width_dim)}
    {\rightskip=0pt\sffamily\small\textbf{\color{scolor}#1}\par#2\par\vskip4pt }}
  \skip_vertical:N \l_tbl_belowcap_skip
}
```